# Cant add image url in scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder

I am new to JavaFX. I have installed a scene builder in NetBeans. 
I created a JavaFX project. Then selecting the JavaFX file, it opens in scene builder correctly. I can add buttons, text fields, and all other staff correctly, but when it comes to adding an image view, I cant add the image.
What I want to say is, after dragging the image view panel in the window, at the right top corner, there is a box to select the image URL. When I click there and select an image from my pc, the image URL is not shown in the box nor the image view, also not when I open it in windows viewer mode.

This is my scenebuilder:
[image: scenebuilder]

I want to select this icon, which is in png format:
[image: Icon to be selected]

After selecting the image, no URL is added:
[image: no url added]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX SceneBuilder ImageView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397367/javafx-scenebuilder-imageview-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

firstly you have to add the image to buildpath. Make package resources and move the image in it. Then open scene builder and locate the image that you dragged to the resources package. The image should appear.